# Firebase design/security for objects like "Groups" entries

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking for people's opinion/expertise (past experiences) for how to structure the design/security for my Firebase JSON tree for things like "Groups"

I have seen/heard 2 possible structures:

```
Groups
 ---- GroupID (provided by firebase)
       ---- GroupPW (provided by user that create new group)
             ---- GroupName (provided by user that create new group)
             ---- etc....
```

Here the group password is directly under the group id, so the user needs to enter both the groupID and groupPW to be able to join the group. But by doing so they group password can never be changed since you can't change/rename keys in Firebase.

Structuring the data this way:

```
Groups
 ---- GroupID 
       ---- GroupPW (provided by user that create new group)
       ---- GroupName (provided by user that create new group)
       ---- etc....
```

Here the GroupPW has been moved under the GroupID (a property of the group) but this leaves the password exposed to anyone who gains access to the structure.

Does anyone have a different structure they implemented, or did they see success utilizing one of the above structures?!

Comment: This seems like an odd way to structure the data in general. Why do you need a group password in the first place? i.e. someone needs to create the group and then add users, what would the function of a password be since the user would already be part of a group? We probably need to understand the use case better to provide any kind of accurate answer.

Comment: The reason is that once the group is created by the admin of the group, users can request to join it by inputting the groupid and password.

Comment: Where would they get the groupid and password?

Comment: it would be sent by the admin as he invites the user to the group. Thats how the app would work.

Answer (score 0):

i see that you can do something like this

so you will save the password under the user who created the group
[image]

and those rules give the possibility only to the owner to acces to the password

[image]

Comment: With this approach, how would a new user submit to join the group, they would have to input the ownerId as part of the request to join the group!?

Comment: no, the other information will be the child of groupId

Comment: if i understand you, then anyone can join the group without entering the password? as long as they know the groupId?

Comment: yes, only the owner can acces to the password, you can add an `approved` field to the user so the owner can accept other user invitation for the group

Comment: can you show how that would work in Firebase?! How would the structure look, and the approval I guess would have to be a list where the group admin would have from all the users asking to join and he approves to finally let the users join the group correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this structure

```
users
  user_0
   name: "Larry"
  user_1
   name: "Mo"
  user_2
   name: "Curly"
  user_3
   name: "Ponch"
  user_4
   name: "John"
```

Assume Larry (user_0) created a group and added user_1 and user_2. Then Ponch (user_3) created a group and added user_4. Here's the structure

```
groups
  group_0
    name: "Stooges"
    owner: user_0
    user_1: true
    user_2: true
  group_1
    name: "Chips"
    owner: "user_3"
    user_4: true
```

With this structure there would be no need for passwords or 'sending invites'

The group creator adds the users they want via the UI, perhaps the users are notified and then put into the group. Rules would only allow groups to be accessed if the users uid_is is the group. If a group creator removes the user, they would cease to be able to access that group.

Rules something along these lines (need to test so dont copy/paste)

```
"rules": {
   ".read": false,
   ".write": false,
   "groups": {
      ".read": false,
      "$group_id": {
        ".read": "root.child('groups').child($group_id).child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": //same as read
       }
    },
```

Comment: yes this works for if the admin does all the addition of the users to his group, but it does not address where the users can join the group if the owner( admin) provides the groupid and password for users to add themselves via the UI which is currently the plan.

Comment: You really dont need additional passwords and extra steps sending emails to invite users etc. That process should just be a simple step in the app where the creator of the group selects the users he wants to add. Super simple and greatly decreases the complexity and logistics of adding a user via emails, additional passwords etc. Also, Rules is what you use to secure your data and limit access - having  another password kind of goes around the already built-in functionality.

Comment: @learningiOS Along those same lines, if the group names are viewable by all users, as a user is browsing and wants to access a group, he can (in the UI) click a request access button and the owner would receive an event that a user wants to have access. He could then allow that which would simply add the uid: true to the group node and then that user would have access. Very simple to implement and extremely flexible.

Comment: @learningiOS The other downside to your solution is that *anyone* that has  the password can access the group. That's very insecure! With my solution, it's locked down to only those users that should have access and the group admin controls that at all times. What if the admin wants to remove a user? Then he has to change the password and then notify all of the other users that the password changed. Wouldn't it just be easier to remove the uid from the group?